# Who is this character in Little Baby Bum?

Tags: character, little-baby-bum

I’ve been trying to piece together who is who in *Little Baby Bum*, most of the characters are characters from a particular nursery rhyme but I’m really struggling to name this girl between Jacus and Mia.

[image]

And again in the Indian *Twinkle Twinkle Little Star*.

[image]

Who is she?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe she is Polly

She’s the only character (apart from the doctor) in Polly had a Dolly.

She’s also present in Polly Put the Kettle on.